# What's the marginal cost of ASIC production?

Tags: asic

It's been selling for $10k. How much does it cost to produce those?

Comment: What's been selling for $10k? There are multiple manufacturers of ASICs with a range of different devices for sale.

Answer (score 2):

From this thread:

http://www.edaboard.com/thread115517.html

About $2, depending on the size.  That's the cost of the *second* chip.  The first one cost half a million dollars.

I saw other threads with very different prices but I imagine that it's under $100.